# I broke fossil-scm - SQLITE_NOTADB

Tags: fossil

In the Q&A style of stack exchange, I had this error and couldn't find a solution.

The accident was cause by me typing:

```
fossil update a_filename
```

This leads to corruption of the fossil-scm settings which outputs:

```
SQLITE_NOTADB: file is not a database
D:\bin\fossil.exe
SQLITE_NOTADB: file is not a database
D:\bin\fossil.exe: file is not a database
PRAGMA database_list
SQLITE_NOTADB: file is not a database
D:\bin\fossil.exe: file is not a database
PRAGMA database_list
SQLITE_NOTADB: file is not a database
D:\bin\fossil.exe: file is not a database
PRAGMASQLITE_NOTADB: file is not a database
^C^C
```

This runs forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to re-sync:

```
fossil sync https://<my_username>@<url>
```

which will prompt for password and deliver a status message that everything is okay.

Comment: FYI: I performed `fossil remote` and it was pointing to the wrong source. So I corrected the remote... and the subsequent `commit` worked.